# using NANOSECONDS with @Scheduled, getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exactly one of the 'cron', 'fixedDelay(String)', or 'fixedRate(String)'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduling

I want to schedule a task with nanosecond or microsecond accuracy.
When I use `@Scheduled(fixedRateString ="600000", timeUnit =TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS  )`, I'll get this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'test': Exactly one of the 'cron', 'fixedDelay(String)', or 'fixedRate(String)' attributes is required
```

This is a spring boot project just with minimum dependencies.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
@Component
public class Task {
@Scheduled(fixedRateString ="600000", timeUnit =TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS  )
public void test() {
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("running in "+time);
}
}
```

If I change TimeUnit to Second or millisecond, I'll get no errors.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of spring are you using?

Comment: Please note that sub-millisecond scheduling will not work. Spring uses [`TaskScheduler.(scheduleAtFixedRate)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-) which has a millisecond-resolution for the scheduling period. If you try to specify a value less than a millisecond for the rate it will be rounded down to 0 milliseconds and the underlying `ScheduledExecutorService` will most probably reject schedules with a scheduling period of 0.

Comment: Upon further investigation this seems to be a bug in Spring. If you specify `timeUnit=TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS` it will convert the default values for fixed delay and fixed rate (-1) into 0 milliseconds and then acts as if you had set values for these properties.

Comment: I'm using spring 5 latest version.